# Trigraph translator

Tags: c, c89

Recently I thought about what a program would look like if all its characters that could become trigraphs became trigraphs.  For example

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[10];
}
```

would become

```
int main(void)
??<
    int array??(10??);
??>
```

As a result I decided to make a program using ANSI C89 that takes a file in and converts each character to its corresponding trigraph if it has one and outputs the result to another file.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define WRITE_BUFFER(x, size)                                            \
    do {                                                                 \
        memcpy(buffer + BUFFER_SIZE + write_buffer_length, (x), (size)); \
        write_buffer_length += (size);                                   \
    } while(0)                                                           \

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int j;

    /* ignore the first argument */
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    /* check for invalid arguments */
    if(argc % 2 != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid arguments\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s input output ...\n", argv[-1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Example: %s main.c result.c \n", argv[-1]);
        return -1;
    }

    for(j = 0; j < argc; j += 2) {
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + BUFFER_SIZE * 3];
        FILE *read_file, *write_file;
        size_t bytes_read = BUFFER_SIZE;

        if(strcmp(argv[j], argv[j + 1]) == 0) {
            printf("Warning: using the same file for input and output is not supported\n");
            continue;
        }

        /* open a file for reading */
        if((read_file = fopen(argv[j], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not open %s\n%s", argv[j], strerror(errno));
            return -2;
        }

        /* open a file for writing */
        if((write_file = fopen(argv[j + 1], "w")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not open %s\n%s", argv[j + 1], strerror(errno));
            return -3;
        }

        /* read the file in BUFFER_SIZE chunks */
        while (bytes_read == BUFFER_SIZE) {
            size_t i, write_buffer_length;
            bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, read_file);

            /* process each character in the buffer
             * and if needed convert it to a trigraph
             */

            write_buffer_length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < bytes_read; ++i) {
                char const ch = buffer[i];

                switch (ch) {
                    case '#':
                        WRITE_BUFFER("\?\?=", 3);
                        break;
                    case '[':
                        WRITE_BUFFER("\?\?(", 3);
                        break;
                    case ']':
                        WRITE_BUFFER("\?\?)", 3);
                        break;
                    case '{':
                        WRITE_BUFFER("\?\?<", 3);
                        break;
                    case '}':
                        WRITE_BUFFER("\?\?>", 3);
                        break;
                    case '\\':
                        WRITE_BUFFER("\?\?/", 3);
                        break;
                    case '^':
                        WRITE_BUFFER("\?\?'", 3);
                        break;
                    case '~':
                        WRITE_BUFFER("\?\?-", 3);
                        break;
                    case '|':
                        WRITE_BUFFER("\?\?!", 3);
                        break;
                    default:
                        WRITE_BUFFER(&ch, 1);
                        break;
                }
            }

            fwrite(buffer + BUFFER_SIZE, 1, write_buffer_length, write_file);
        }

        fclose(read_file);
        fclose(write_file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program could be a lot shorter and simpler if you followed the "Unix philosophy."

- Read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`. This eliminates your need to process arguments, and eliminates the `for(j)` loop.
- Trust `fread` and `fwrite` to do I/O buffering on their own. (They do.)

Then your entire program would be something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

void trigraph(char c) {
    putchar('?');
    putchar('?');
    putchar(c);
}

int main() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
            case '\\': trigraph('/'); break;
            case '#': trigraph('='); break;
            [...]
            default: putchar(c); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you want to transform a bunch of files at once, that's as easy as

```
for i in *.c ; do ./a.out < "$i" > "${i%.c}.trigraphed.c" ; done
```

For more on the Unix philosophy of writing simple "pipeline" programs that compose well, I recommend the book [*Software Tools*, by Kernighan and Plauger](https://amzn.to/2J3jfJk); or for that matter [*The C Programming Language*, by Kernighan and Ritchie](https://amzn.to/3e1PZOr).

For an additional exercise, you might try writing a program to *reverse* this operation: replace every trigraph with its corresponding ASCII character.

Comment: For fun, it would be interesting to also see this code with trigraphs applied.

Comment: Well, you can run it through itself. ;) But that does remind me: perhaps the cases should cutely be written as `case '??/': trigraph('/'); break; case '??=': trigraph('='); break;` and so on. This would be either more self-documenting or less self-documenting, depending on your point of view. :)

Answer (score 1):

- There is absolutely no reason why `WRITE_BUFFER` should be a macro and not a function.
- Don't do exotic stuff like `--argc; ++argv;`. C programmers expect argument 0 to be the name of the executable. Similarly, `argc % 2` is weird, why would you check for an even amount of arguments? Check for an *exact* amount of arguments, no more, no less.
- Similarly, you should be able to keep all error handling out of the loops and just do it once. Keep it simple.
- I'd expect the various valid trigraph sequences to be stored in some manner of table, rather than a big `switch`. For example, you could sacrifice 128 bytes data for a fast lookup table based on 7 bit ASCII:

  ```
  const char trigraph [128] = 
  {
    ['#'] = '=',
    ['['] = '(',
    ...
  };

  char in  = ... // input from file
  char out = trigraph[in];
  if(out != 0) // was it a candidate for trigraph replacement?
  {  
    // printf("??%c", out); etc
  ```

Comment: the reason I check for an even amount of arguments is so every file read has a corresponding file to write to and that will not be true when there is an odd amount of arguments.

Comment: @nullptr And why would someone ever use the program with more than 2 files? That's not a very good UI and you gain no performance from it either, since the massive bottleneck here is the file i/o and everything else is negligible. It's a potential security hole too.